# Conditional count and mean by grouped data without filter or left_join

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

How can I calculate the conditional count and mean by grouped data without filter using dplyr? I neither want to shrink the dataset using filter nor want to left_join the data to get the original sized (lengthed) dataset. Is that possible?

Here is a case:

mtcars %>% filter(cyl>4, gear<5) %>% group_by(gear, carb, am) %>% mutate(avg_mpg = mean(mpg, na.rm = T), cnt = n())

How can I get the above results without using filter or left_join?

Comment: Did you meant `mtcars %>% group_by(gear, carb, am) %>% mutate(avg_mpg = mean(mpg[cyl>4 & gear< 5], na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: @ckrun Can you include count to your suggested answer please?

Comment: Yes, `mtcars %>% group_by(gear, carb, am) %>% mutate(avg_mpg = mean(mpg[cyl>4 & gear< 5], na.rm = TRUE), cnt= n())`

Comment: Is this what you want?\

Comment: Count should also have those condition like cyl>4 & gear< 5.

Comment: In that case, `cnt = sum(cyl>4 & gear <5))`

Comment: Fantastic!! Is this the common way to create other aggregate statistics? Also can you put that as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: It depends on the conditions.  Usually, people want to have a summarised dataset with one row for each group, so you may use `summarise`.  here you don't want to `filter`, or summarise but want to have to have fulll dataset with the conditions applied\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create the condition as a logical column and use that to subset the 'mpg' by group to get the `mean` value, and similarly the 'cnt' is calculated as `sum` of the logical vector

```
mtcars %>%
       mutate(ind = cyl > 4 & gear < 5) %>%
       group_by(gear, carb, am) %>%
       mutate(avg_mpg = mean(mpg[ind], na.rm= TRUE),
              cnt = sum(ind)) %>%
       select(-ind)
```

NOTE: The 'ind' column is created only because we are using the conditions multiple times.